# Tweepy connection error: host has forcbily removed the connection

Tags: python, tweepy

```
# OAuth2.0 Version 
import tweepy as tw
import time
import pandas as pd

#Put your Bearer Token in the parenthesis below
client = tw.Client(bearer_token='removedfromcode',
                      wait_on_rate_limit=True)

# -is:retweet means I don't want retweets
# lang:en is asking for the tweets to be in english

query = 'Manchester United Man United Man Utd lang:en -is:retweet'


ManUtd_tweets = []
ManUtd_tweets_ids = []


while True:
    try:
        for tweet in tw.Paginator(client.search_all_tweets, query=query,
                          user_fields = ['username','public_metrics','description', 'location'],
                          tweet_fields=['text', 'created_at','public_metrics'],
                          start_time = '2021-01-01T00:00:00Z',
                          end_time = '2022-01-01T00:00:00Z', max_results=100) \
                          .flatten(limit=1000000):

            
            ManUtd_tweets.append(tweet)
            ManUtd_tweets_ids.append(tweet['id'])

            df = pd.DataFrame(ManUtd_tweets)

      

    except BaseException as error:
                   time.sleep(60)
                   print('Error', str(error))
    break



df
```

The above code times out after a while, i get the connection error 10054 - an existing connection was forceably closed by the remote host.

any ideas of how to get around this for tweepy?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tweepy connection time out error 1 million tweets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72103468/tweepy-connection-time-out-error-1-million-tweets)

Comment: Hi Michael, apologies i did not see your message, it did not unfortunately, I am using snsscrape to accomplish this now. thanks for your message